# Retrieve value from query string and send it in a form as HIDDEN VALUE - javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, post, hidden-field

I'm trying to figure how to post from an HTML to another page andm, in the meantime, insert values in the hidden form BEFORE send the form itself.

```html
<html>

    <head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="TEXT/HTML;CHARSET=UTF-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE"> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="-1">
    
    
<script>

var param1var = getQueryVariable("TARGET");

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      alert("TARGET FOUND!");
        alert(pair[1]);
        return pair[1];
    
    }
  } 
    

  alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
}    
    
</script>    
    </head>
    
    
<form name="LOGIN" action="/mynextpage/mypage.html" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><P><span>Username :</span></P></td>
          <td><P><input name="USER" type="text" value="" style="width:150px" /></P></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><P><span>Password :</span></P></td>
          <td><P><input name="PASSWORD" type="password" value="" style="width:150px" /></P></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
                    <INPUT type=HIDDEN name="TARGET" value=param1var
    
    <P>
     <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
     <input name="Reset" type="reset" />
    </P>
   </div>
  </form>
```

The first part of the javascript code is able to capture a TARGET value I need to use: it is present (i'm calling it param1var) and I'm able to alert out just for confirmation.

Now, in the form, I need to:
- insert in the input hidden the value retrieved by the above code (so, the param1var value)
- post the entire for to the page /mynextpage/mypage.html that will take username, password and the hidden value

Can you help me on how to achieve it?
I can use only html page as first page.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

document.querySelector('.target').value=param1var;
at the same time your hidden input put the class target